# Plot conditional density curve `P(Y|X)` along a linear regression line

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

This is my data frame, with two columns `Y` (response) and `X` (covariate):

```
## Editor edit: use `dat` not `data`
dat <- structure(list(Y = c(NA, -1.793, -0.642, 1.189, -0.823, -1.715, 
    1.623, 0.964, 0.395, -3.736, -0.47, 2.366, 0.634, -0.701, -1.692, 
    0.155, 2.502, -2.292, 1.967, -2.326, -1.476, 1.464, 1.45, -0.797, 
    1.27, 2.515, -0.765, 0.261, 0.423, 1.698, -2.734, 0.743, -2.39, 
    0.365, 2.981, -1.185, -0.57, 2.638, -1.046, 1.931, 4.583, -1.276, 
    1.075, 2.893, -1.602, 1.801, 2.405, -5.236, 2.214, 1.295, 1.438, 
    -0.638, 0.716, 1.004, -1.328, -1.759, -1.315, 1.053, 1.958, -2.034, 
    2.936, -0.078, -0.676, -2.312, -0.404, -4.091, -2.456, 0.984, 
    -1.648, 0.517, 0.545, -3.406, -2.077, 4.263, -0.352, -1.107, 
    -2.478, -0.718, 2.622, 1.611, -4.913, -2.117, -1.34, -4.006, 
    -1.668, -1.934, 0.972, 3.572, -3.332, 1.094, -0.273, 1.078, -0.587, 
    -1.25, -4.231, -0.439, 1.776, -2.077, 1.892, -1.069, 4.682, 1.665, 
    1.793, -2.133, 1.651, -0.065, 2.277, 0.792, -3.469, 1.48, 0.958, 
    -4.68, -2.909, 1.169, -0.941, -1.863, 1.814, -2.082, -3.087, 
    0.505, -0.013, -0.12, -0.082, -1.944, 1.094, -1.418, -1.273, 
    0.741, -1.001, -1.945, 1.026, 3.24, 0.131, -0.061, 0.086, 0.35, 
    0.22, -0.704, 0.466, 8.255, 2.302, 9.819, 5.162, 6.51, -0.275, 
    1.141, -0.56, -3.324, -8.456, -2.105, -0.666, 1.707, 1.886, -3.018, 
    0.441, 1.612, 0.774, 5.122, 0.362, -0.903, 5.21, -2.927, -4.572, 
    1.882, -2.5, -1.449, 2.627, -0.532, -2.279, -1.534, 1.459, -3.975, 
    1.328, 2.491, -2.221, 0.811, 4.423, -3.55, 2.592, 1.196, -1.529, 
    -1.222, -0.019, -1.62, 5.356, -1.885, 0.105, -1.366, -1.652, 
    0.233, 0.523, -1.416, 2.495, 4.35, -0.033, -2.468, 2.623, -0.039, 
    0.043, -2.015, -4.58, 0.793, -1.938, -1.105, 0.776, -1.953, 0.521, 
    -1.276, 0.666, -1.919, 1.268, 1.646, 2.413, 1.323, 2.135, 0.435, 
    3.747, -2.855, 4.021, -3.459, 0.705, -3.018, 0.779, 1.452, 1.523, 
    -1.938, 2.564, 2.108, 3.832, 1.77, -3.087, -1.902, 0.644, 8.507
    ), X = c(0.056, 0.053, 0.033, 0.053, 0.062, 0.09, 0.11, 0.124, 
    0.129, 0.129, 0.133, 0.155, 0.143, 0.155, 0.166, 0.151, 0.144, 
    0.168, 0.171, 0.162, 0.168, 0.169, 0.117, 0.105, 0.075, 0.057, 
    0.031, 0.038, 0.034, -0.016, -0.001, -0.031, -0.001, -0.004, 
    -0.056, -0.016, 0.007, 0.015, -0.016, -0.016, -0.053, -0.059, 
    -0.054, -0.048, -0.051, -0.052, -0.072, -0.063, 0.02, 0.034, 
    0.043, 0.084, 0.092, 0.111, 0.131, 0.102, 0.167, 0.162, 0.167, 
    0.187, 0.165, 0.179, 0.177, 0.192, 0.191, 0.183, 0.179, 0.176, 
    0.19, 0.188, 0.215, 0.221, 0.203, 0.2, 0.191, 0.188, 0.19, 0.228, 
    0.195, 0.204, 0.221, 0.218, 0.224, 0.233, 0.23, 0.258, 0.268, 
    0.291, 0.275, 0.27, 0.276, 0.276, 0.248, 0.228, 0.223, 0.218, 
    0.169, 0.188, 0.159, 0.156, 0.15, 0.117, 0.088, 0.068, 0.057, 
    0.035, 0.021, 0.014, -0.005, -0.014, -0.029, -0.043, -0.046, 
    -0.068, -0.073, -0.042, -0.04, -0.027, -0.018, -0.021, 0.002, 
    0.002, 0.006, 0.015, 0.022, 0.039, 0.044, 0.055, 0.064, 0.096, 
    0.093, 0.089, 0.173, 0.203, 0.216, 0.208, 0.225, 0.245, 0.23, 
    0.218, -0.267, 0.193, -0.013, 0.087, 0.04, 0.012, -0.008, 0.004, 
    0.01, 0.002, 0.008, 0.006, 0.013, 0.018, 0.019, 0.018, 0.021, 
    0.024, 0.017, 0.015, -0.005, 0.002, 0.014, 0.021, 0.022, 0.022, 
    0.02, 0.025, 0.021, 0.027, 0.034, 0.041, 0.04, 0.038, 0.033, 
    0.034, 0.031, 0.029, 0.029, 0.029, 0.022, 0.021, 0.019, 0.021, 
    0.016, 0.007, 0.002, 0.011, 0.01, 0.01, 0.003, 0.009, 0.015, 
    0.018, 0.017, 0.021, 0.021, 0.021, 0.022, 0.023, 0.025, 0.022, 
    0.022, 0.019, 0.02, 0.023, 0.022, 0.024, 0.022, 0.025, 0.025, 
    0.022, 0.027, 0.024, 0.016, 0.024, 0.018, 0.024, 0.021, 0.021, 
    0.021, 0.021, 0.022, 0.016, 0.015, 0.017, -0.017, -0.009, -0.003, 
    -0.012, -0.009, -0.008, -0.024, -0.023)), .Names = c("Y", "X"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -234L), class = "data.frame")
```

With this I run a OLS regression: `lm(dat[,1] ~ dat[,2])`.

At a set of values: `X = quantile(dat[,2], c(0.1, 0.5, 0.7))`, I would like to plot a graph similar to the following, with conditional density `P(Y|X)` displaying along the regression line.

[image]

How can I do this in R? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I call your dataset `dat`. Don't use `data` as it masks R function `data`.

```
dat <- na.omit(dat)  ## retain only complete cases

## use proper formula rather than `$` or `[,]`;
## otherwise you get trouble in prediction with `predict.lm`
fit <- lm(Y ~ X, dat)

## prediction point, as given in your question
xp <- quantile(dat$X, probs = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.7), names = FALSE)

## make prediction and only keep `$fit` and `$se.fit`
pred <- predict.lm(fit, newdata = data.frame(X = xp), se.fit = TRUE)[1:2]

#$fit
#         1          2          3 
#0.20456154 0.14319857 0.00678734 
#
#$se.fit
#        1         2         3 
#0.2205000 0.1789353 0.1819308
```

To understand the theory behind the following, read [Plotting conditional density of prediction after linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40615864/4891738). Now I am to use `mapply` function to apply the same computation to multiple points:

```
## a function to make 101 sample points from conditional density
f <- function (mu, sig) {
  x <- seq(mu - 3.2 * sig, mu + 3.2 * sig, length = 101)
  dx <- dnorm(x, mu, sig)
  cbind(x, dx)
  }

## apply `f` to all `xp`
lst <- mapply(f, pred[[1]], pred[[2]], SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

## To plot rotated density curve, we basically want to plot `(dx, x)`
## but scaling `(alpha * dx, x)` is needed for good scaling with regression line
## Also to plot rotated density along the regression line,
## a shift is needed: `(alpha * dx + xp, x)`
## The following function adds rotated, scaled density to a regression line
## a "for-loop" is used for readability, with no loss of efficiency.
## (make sure there is an existing plot; otherwise you get `plot.new` error!!)
addrsd <- function (xp, lst, alpha = 1) {
  for (i in 1:length(xp)) {
    x0 <- xp[i]; mat <- lst[[i]]
    dx. <- alpha * mat[, 2] + x0  ## rescale and shift
    x. <- mat[, 1]
    lines(dx., x., col = "gray")  ## rotate and plot
    segments(x0, x.[1], x0, x.[101], col = "gray")  ## a local axis
    }
  }
```

Now let's see the picture:

```
## This is one simple way to draw the regression line
## A better way is to generate and grid and predict on the grid
## In later example I will show this
plot(dat$X, fit$fitted, type = "l", ylim = c(-0.6, 1))

## we try `alpha = 0.01`;
## you can also try `alpha = 1` in raw scale to see what it looks like
addrsd(xp, lst, 0.01)
```

[image]

Note, we have only scaled the height of the density, not its span. The span sort of implies confidence band, and should not be scaled. Consider further overlaying confidence band on the plot. If the use of `matplot` is not clear, read [How do I change colours of confidence interval lines when using `matlines` for prediction plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822268/4891738).

```
## A grid is necessary for nice regression plot
X.grid <- seq(min(dat$X), max(dat$X), length = 101)

## 95%-CI based on t-statistic
CI <- predict.lm(fit, newdata = data.frame(X = X.grid), interval = "confidence")

## use `matplot`
matplot(X.grid, CI, type = "l", col = c(1, 2, 2), lty = c(1, 2, 2))

## add rotated, scaled conditional density
addrsd(xp, lst, 0.01)
```

[image]

You see that the span of the density curve agrees with the confidence ribbon.